# Passing Object as an parameter in Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In Web Api How can pass object as parameter

```
// GET api/values/{can be any serilizable object}
public string Get(object data)
{
    return "value";
}



   [Serializable]
    public class RequestData
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to return it as? string, json?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop an ASP.NET Web API to accept a complex object as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377423/how-to-develop-an-asp-net-web-api-to-accept-a-complex-object-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Your object will have to be sent in the request as JSON.  `[Serializable]` is different kind of serialization. Here we talking either JSON or XML serialization and it is built-in

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(RequestData requestData)
{
    HttpResponseMessage retMsg;
    // pack your message here, select serializer {json, xml}, etc
    return respMessage;
}



// [Serializable] - not needed, good old POCO is fine
public class RequestData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```