# How to develop an ASP.NET Web API to accept a list object as GET parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have read this link:
[How to develop an ASP.NET Web API to accept a complex object as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377423/how-to-develop-an-asp-net-web-api-to-accept-a-complex-object-as-parameter)

And implemented the code just fine. Now I want to convert the 'firstName' parameter to accept an `IList<string>` collection. I have modified the class like this:

```
public class MyApiParameters
{
    public IList<string> FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping that the accepted URL would look like this:

```
http://localhost:58256/api/articles?firstName=matthew,andrew,philip,david&LastName=smith&birthDate=12-12-2012
```

But the parameter is only interpreted as a list if I pass it like this:

```
http://localhost:58256/api/articles?firstName=matthew&firstName=andrew&firstName=philip&firstName=david&LastName=smith&birthDate=12-12-2012
```

Comment: Could you show me Action declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Add `[FromUri]` attribute annotation before you parameter and pass the second way of passing values you have mentioned in your question.

```
public MyApiParameters GetTest([FromUri]MyApiParameters test)
{
    return test;
}
```